# where can I find a Locky Ransomware virus samples?

Tags: microsoft-word, virus, anti-virus, avg-antivirus

I need a locky ransomware virus sample to test it on VM for my project. Where can I get one working sample ?(Any microsoft word or excel files would work)

Comment: I have not been able to find any actual samples just ones analyzed [Here](https://blog.malwarebytes.org/threat-analysis/2016/03/look-into-locky/) and the site Ransom site Address [Here](http://pastebin.com/jTS0htmx) although if anyone else has anything I am going to be watching this.

Comment: Needs some searching but malwr.com allows you to download the samples. Also https://www.reddit.com/r/Malware/comments/472pkl/sample_of_locky/. The Locky virus is usually sent via e-mail in files with "invoice" in their names. You could also search for that.

Comment: @Spokey the link you provided downloads the file but shows automation error after enabling the MACRO. Is their anyway to solve the automation error